# Using `wmctrl` and `skip_taskbar to remove an application from the Alt-Tab switcher works for Firefox and Google Chrome but not for CopyQ

Tags: linux, bash, wmctrl

Based on the information at [Remove app from alt-tab switcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113956/remove-app-from-alt-tab-switcher) I was able to successfully prevent Google Chrome and Firefox from appearing when I press Alt-Tab by using...

1. `wmctrl -r "Google Chrome" -b add,skip_taskbar`, and
2. `wmctrl -r "Firefox" -b add,skip_taskbar`, but
3. inexplicably (to me) `wmctrl -r "CopyQ" -b add,skip_taskbar` does not prevent [CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) from appearing when I press Alt-Tab.

How can I prevent **CopyQ** from appearing when I press Alt-Tab?